# Beginner needs help: I can solve the problem, but I can't see it

Tags: javascript

I'm new at learning JavaScript and I got an exercise which I try to understand. I don't really understand the problem in the code. I solved the problem anyway, but I dont see the problem :D

The practice is to solve a mistake in the code, which produces the wrong outcome:

(Note: new SimpleImage is creating a blank image and is working fine. The whole picture has all RGB color values set to 0, so it's all black.)

```
// Create an clear image with 200 x 200 pixels:
var img = new SimpleImage(200,200);

// Change the colors so, you get 4 x 50x50 fields with the colors red, green, magenta and blue.
for (var px of img.values()){
  var x = px.getX();
  var y = px.getY();
  if (x < img.getWidth()/2){
    px.setRed(255);
  }
  if (y>img.getHeight()/2){
    px.setBlue(255);
  }
  else {
    px.setGreen(255);
  }
}
print (img);

//Why is the top left yellow?
```

The outcome should be:
Red (top left), Green (top right),
Magenta (down left), Blue (top right).

Instead you get Yellow in the top left (should be red).

The code has 2 IF's and one ELSE.

First IF says: If the pixels x is smaller than the half of the pictures width, make it red. So everything on the left sight is red.

Second If says: If the pixels y is bigger  than the half of the height, make it blue. So everything in the down half gets blue. Bc down left is already red: Blue+Red=Magenta. Everything fine so far.

The only untouched part now is the top right, which has to become Green. The ELSE statement also says: Otherwise make it Green. Top Right pixels were not touched yet, so they become Green.

What I don't understand here: Why is the top left field now getting Yellow? The ELSE statement shouldn't touch those at all. But their Green value is getting updated anyway and I don't get why. Can somebody help me?

(I solved it by telling with ELSE IF to touch ONLY the Green value, if x is better than the half AND y is smaller than the half... But I anyway am looking for the reason why red becomes yellow...)

Looking for someone smarter than me to explain me the problem :D

Greetings

Comment: What is the `SimpleImage` function? Looks important, since the whole code depends on it

Comment: @CertainPerformance its not a function, its a class

Comment: The `else` statement is only connected to the second `if`. So it's executed whenever the second `if` condition is false, even if the first `if` condition was true. You probably want `else if` for the second `if`.

Comment: @frederic Both classes and functions can be invoked with `new`. Regardless, OP needs to post it for answerers to have a decent idea of what's going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like this, there are two independent if statements. One is about x axis and the other is y. When you run the first if statement left side of the image is painted red. When it is the turn of the second conditional statement, it does not care about other statements it only looks whether y value is on bottom of the canvas or top. If it is bottom, it paints blue but OTHERWISE it paints green. It looks at the image as a whole. Two separate if statements do not affect each other. Red and green combined results in yellow colour.

[image]

Comment: Hi!
Ah, that explains it to me. My understanding here was wrong (as expected).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help, I suggest looking over conditionals again just for good measure.

Comment: On the other hand... Still questions: Is ELSE doing always the opposite? So... I guess its like: If Y is bigger than height, than make the pixels blue. Otherwise, (Y is smaller) make those pixels green. Correct? Is there a possibility to trigger ELSE conditioned on both IFs? Like: if the first IF and the second IF are false, execute ELSE on the rest? Or do I need to specify the "rest"?

Comment: @Brinks basically add another expression to if statement. You say if(y is smaller), instead you can say if(y is smaller and x is bigger) so as not to interfere with the red on the left. It would look something like 
```if(y<img.getHeight()/2 && x > img.getWidth()/2) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Top left means x < img.getWidth()/2 and y < img.getHeight()/2.
Si it goes both in

```
px.setRed(255);
```

and

```
px.setGreen(255);
```

RGB 255 255 0 is yellow.

Answer (score 0):

(from the comment of @Barmar):

> The else statement is only connected to the second if. So it's executed whenever
> the second if condition is false, even if the first if condition was true. You
> probably want else if for the second if.

Your code sets first red for the left half, then it sets blue for the lower half ***or*** green for the upper half. Red + green == yellow.